# why aggregate on Date returns numeric - R

Tags: r, date, data.table, aggregate

I have a data.table of a few million rows and trying to aggregate on a date field. the result returned is numeric (instead of date) and I can't figure out why. I've been trying to reproduce the example but to no avail. 
Here is a sample of my code:

```
DT <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,1), col1 = c('Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y',' Y', 'N', 'N'), col2 = as.Date(c('2001-01-01', '2002-01-01', '2003-01-01', '2004-01-01','2005-01-01', NA, '2007-01-01', '2008-01-01', NA), '%Y-%m-%d'))

> DT
   ID col1       col2
1:  1    Y 2001-01-01
2:  1    N 2002-01-01
3:  2    Y 2003-01-01
4:  1    Y 2004-01-01
5:  2    N 2005-01-01
6:  3    Y       <NA>
7:  2    Y 2007-01-01
8:  3    N 2008-01-01
9:  1    N       <NA>

DT_agg = DT[, .(max_date = if(!any(col1 == "Y")) NA_real_ else max(col2[which(col1 == "Y")], na.rm = TRUE) ) , by = .(ID)]
Warning message:
In max.default(NA_real_, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf



 # this works on the sample data.table. 
 # and it's desired output. But it doesn't work on my 
 # real data.table. max_date has numeric values instead (e.g. 11124, 22354, etc.)
> DT_agg
   ID   max_date
1:  1 2004-01-01
2:  2 2003-01-01
3:  3       <NA>

# this is what i want for my results. but in my real table max_date becomes numeric and unusable
> class(DT_agg$max_date)
[1] "Date"
```

in the above sample code `DT_agg$max_date` is a date class. but for some reason in my table it is numeric. I run the same aggregation on another date field and it's fine.

Comment: Do you mean that this works on the sample data you have provided but not on your real data ?

Comment: yes. that's correct. I'll edit my question to make it more clear. this works in the sample provided but not on my large real data.table

Comment: i think `col2[which(col1 == "Y")]` is of `length(0)` for some cases after removing NAs causing that warning. You can replicate with this dataset: `DT <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,1), 
    col1 = rep("Y", 9L), 
    col2 = as.Date(rep(NA, 9L), '%Y-%m-%d'))`

Comment: `!any(col1 == "Y")` can be simplified to `all(col1 != "Y")`.

Comment: Regarding your problem. Would replacing `NA_real_` with something like `as.Date(NA_real_, origin = "2000-01-01")` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

`ifelse` is where things are happening. The Yes and No clauses need to be the same class.

## My solution:

First, aggregate by  both columns

```
> DT[,max(col2),by=list(ID,col1)]
   ID col1         V1
1:  1    Y 2004-01-01
2:  1    N       <NA>
3:  2    Y 2003-01-01
4:  2    N 2005-01-01
5:  3    Y       <NA>
6:  2    Y 2007-01-01
7:  3    N 2008-01-01
```

Then just take the Y's.

```
> DT[,max(col2),by=list(ID,col1)][col1=='Y']
   ID col1         V1
1:  1    Y 2004-01-01
2:  2    Y 2003-01-01
3:  3    Y       <NA>
```

Now remove the unneeded second column, (or assign it

```
> DT[,max(col2),by=list(ID,col1)][col1=='Y'][ , .(ID,V1)]
   ID         V1
1:  1 2004-01-01
2:  2 2003-01-01
3:  3       <NA>
```

Also, the second and third steps can be combined:

```r
 DT[,max(col2),by=list(ID,col1)][col1=='Y', .(ID,max_date=V1)]
```

**Update**: When I experimented with `ifelse`, I found that's where your conversion is occurring

```r
 k=as.Date('2001-01-01')
> k
[1] "2001-01-01"
> as.integer(k)
[1] 11323
> max(k,NA)
[1] NA
> min(k,NA)
[1] NA
> ifelse(Y=='N',k,NA)
Error in ifelse(Y == "N", k, NA) : object 'Y' not found
> Y='N'
> ifelse(Y=='N',k,NA)
[1] 11323
```

**Update 2**

If you try to execute the fast data table version of `ifelse`,  you can see what the issue is. The cast is occurring in ordinary `ifelse` because the 'Yes' and 'No' clauses, are not the same class, and R has to take time to  cast them, which is also giving you a performance hit. Remember: `ifelse` *has to be vectorizable*.  To do this, the `Yes` and `No` clauses _*must* be of the same class.

```
# the double colon is not really necessary.  I'm just
# doing it to emphasize the provenance of `fifelse`

> data.table::fifelse(Y=='N',k,23)
Error in data.table::fifelse(Y == "N", k, 23) : 
  'yes' has different class than 'no'. Please make sure that both arguments have the same class.
```

Comment: This works but my only issue with this solution is that I have multiple of these aggregations each on different columns. which means for each date column I have to do a separate aggregate and then combine then together. Just a bit ugly. :) I guess if it doesn't work any other way, this is what I will do. I'm just wondering why aggregation operation on dates is unstable. Not knowing why it's happening is really a bugger!

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira : also,just thought of this - if the number of aggregations you are doing is fixed (not dependent on your data), why not do a master aggregation first, on all your categories, and then work on whittling it down?

Comment: that is very helpful!! Thanks a million. Mystery solved.